# Javascript objects and arrays references behaving different deppending on the depth

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reference

Just trying to understand why this is happening.

I was experimenting a bit with javascript arrays, objects and references to the objects. Then I reached a point where I don't understand anymore.

I create an array that holds an object; then when I do a reference to that object and change a property; the values of the original and the reference  are changed automatically. Obviously because it's a reference and not a copy.

I was expecting the same when I create an array with an object that holds and array with one other object but somehow in that case the original object remains untouched.

Probably It has a really simple explanation that I don't know right now. Someone could explain me that?

Thanks!

```js
var foo = [ 
  { 
    "bar": "bar" 
  } 
];

var ref = foo[0];
ref.bar = "new bar";

console.info(foo[0].bar);                // output: new bar
console.info(ref.bar);                   // output: new bar
console.info(foo[0].bar === ref.bar);    // output: true

var foo2 = [ 
  { 
    "bar2": [
       { "nested": "nested" }
    ] 
  } 
];

var ref2 = foo2[0].bar2;
ref2.nested = "nested 2";

console.info(foo2[0].bar2[0].nested);                 // output: nested
console.info(ref2.nested);                             // output: nested 2
console.info(foo2[0].bar2[0].nested === ref2.nested);  // output: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is going fine. Nothing has changed. you understood well. 
It's just that you put *foo2[0].bar2* in var *ref2*.

```
var ref2 = foo2[0].bar2;
```

you see *foo2[0].bar2* is **an array** here. when you did

```
*ref2.nested = "nested 2";*
```

It added a new object to *ref2*.
what you want to do is

```
*var ref2 = foo2[0].bar2[0];*
```

Or anything else subtle.
Javascript is same friend. It's just us who lose reference.